# grab user inputted text from input

Tags: jquery, input

I have an `<input Id="inputTest">` and I have tried grabbing the value, `$('#inputTest').val();` but the problem is when a user types text it does not hold it in the value until the form is submitted.

How can I capture what the user types in before submitting the form?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: will only get the value at moment your code runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us `keyup()` to get the value as it is entered -

```
$('input[name="foo"]').keyup(function() {
    $('#foo_result').html( $(this).val() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uxs14yc9/

Answer (score 2):

I was working on the Demo when a correct answer Popped up :)) anyway Lets not get it to waste. Yes thats correct. (keyup)

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/637oaex3/

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#input", function(event){
var txt = $(this).val();
$("#text").html(txt);
});
```